# What is the Renderer class for UIXIterator

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

**Summary**
What is the renderer class for UIXIterator(af:iterator)?

**Background**

I am writing a component and I am planning to extend UIXIterator just like UIXTable does. My component will basically accept the same kind of data binding as UIXIterator/UIXTable does. The only difference will be in the rendering and the client behavior.

I am conducting some preliminary checks to see if this is feasible and how I will go about doing this. I have already determined that most likely I can just extend the component and tag classes(UIXIterator and UIXIteratorTag respectively). The only thing that I am not able to find is the renderer class for UIXIterator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default Renderer. It renders himself, unless you did not set rendererType in UIXIterator class.